# SKStoreReviewController - auto populate body text

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, app-store-connect, skstorereviewcontroller

I'm trying to implement SKStoreReviewController to make users rate/review within our app, instead of throwing the appstore on the screen. I wanted to auto-populate some user data in the store controller as body text(same as mail app supports to do so) but I know there are no public properties supporting to add such data in SKStoreReviewController. But my question is, is there any other way to achieve the above requirement? Please drop your comments.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43177249/skstorereviewcontroller-how-to-use-it-in-a-correct-way/49593419#49593419). Maybe it will help

Comment: @JaydeepPatel thanks, but  the links helps to integrate the review controller, my answer isn't listed.

Comment: If Apple wanted you to do that, they would have provided a property or function to do it.

Comment: Yes, they should. I'm searching for other ways to do so. Thanks

Comment: You think they should, they think they shouldn't, so they didn't. Any method you manage to find will be private api and not permitted in the store.

Comment: yes i knew apple from years. I don't want to reject my app with those private api's included. Im generally searching for other options to do the job. That's it.