# Storekit App review/Rating once submitted iOS

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

Once the user have given the review will he be promoted again(Submitted) if he follows a different journey in the app where the app review is called again ?

In other word's once submitted the review will the user be promoted again ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/43227699/2797838

Comment: It is not a duplicate, the question is different.. I have asked about the submit review , and the link you shared show's how to create an app review through store kit

Comment: the answer was possible duplicate, not the question